# Hide p-column header highlight in PrimeNG DataTables

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, primeng

How do I hide the column-header highlight (blue) that persists after a column is clicked for sorting purposes? I have no need to 'select' the column when a user simply clicks it to change the sort order.

Is there an attribute that I can use to switch-off column selection, similar to the way row selection can be disabled with 'selectionMode="none"'?

Comment: **PrimeFaces** != PrimeNG

Comment: Ok - Can you explain? Who's who?

Comment: PrimeTek are developers of both codebases, PrimeFaces and PrimeNG. PrimeFaces is for JavaServer, and PrimeNG is for Angular2. Do I have that correct?

Comment: Yes, and the confusion is caused by PrimeNG, PrimeUI etc are all only accesible via the primefaces.org site (PrimeFaces being the original/first framework

Comment: Sound like some refactoring is required(!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to overwrite this line of css according to your needs.

.ui-datatable th.ui-state-active { background: #186ba0;color: #ffffff; }

Comment: I like this and it works, but is it the 'expected' technique, or is it a work around for not being able to 'switch-off' column selection via table attributes. Cheers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no built in way for this. 2nd alternative you can change it js to not to add .ui-state-active to a sorted column but css way is easier in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.ui-datatable th.ui-state-active{
  outline:none;
}
```